# Why is an error produced due to the MySQL driver and JDBC when I run my Spring Boot app?

Tags: java, jdbc

When running the Spring Boot app, I have these error messages:

> "Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl,
> mysql://localhost:3306"

and

> "Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:
> Failed to instantiate
> [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]:
> Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested
> exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl,
> mysql://localhost:3306".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGwLU.png)

I have added the dependencies in the POM file:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.27</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Java version is:

```xml
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
</properties>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just from a quick look at it, it looks like your jdbc connector address isn't complete. You are missing a db there, something like
`jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ReallyNiceDb`

In MySQL, you will need to create a database, in this case, called `ReallyNiceDb`. Then, to this database, you will need to allow your user to interact with that database.
More info can be found here:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/creating-database.html

Comment: I understand, but where should I create the database? Is it necessary to use the Bash terminal, as with PostgreSQL and the psql command?

Comment: So what software are you using? MySQL or PostgreSQL? Both have their own drivers. Here, you have a setup for MySQL, PostgreSQL will require you to change the driver dependency, JDBC url and then yes, create a database in PostgreSQL. These links might help you with the Postgres

[mkyong](https://mkyong.com/jdbc/how-do-connect-to-postgresql-with-jdbc-driver-java/)
[tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_create_database.htm)

Comment: This is what I don't understand: where can I find MySQL software with an UI? I prefer to stay with MySQL.

Comment: In the terminal command line of IntelliJ, why have I received an error when trying to connect to MySQL? The message of the error is: "ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)"

Comment: I find it odd that the exception message is _"Driver com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, mysql://localhost:3306"_, that is without the `jdbc:` prefix, but maybe that is just how the exception message is generated by Spring.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice. The main problem is that the last version of the MySQL driver doesn't work with some versions before MacOS 12. After taking the previous version, MySQL works, and I can create databases and tables with the iTerm command line.